# How do I lock kivy app in portrait orientation

Tags: python, kivy

I have a kivy appplication that does not look so good on android devices when in landscape mode. I've tried to lock it in portrait mode using buidozer.spec's `orientation = portrait` but didnt work.

```
# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait
```

Answer (score 0):

try disabling these in python near the top of your main.py

```
from kivy import platform
if platform != 'android':
    Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)  # Prevent window from being resized
```

Comment: you mean `if platform == 'android'`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).